# Filter visible/hidden bootstrap columns using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Any JQuery assistance to show/hide bootstrap columns on click buttons?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Category1</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Category2</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Category3</button>
</div>
```

This should control visible column/s in animated transition

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Category1 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
...
</div>
<!-- Category2 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
...
</div>
<!-- Category2 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Please explain a bit more. Do you want to hide or show the category div on click of respective buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Try with JQuery to toggle hide/show on button click for respective category DIV.

JQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function toggle the display property of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var $btn = $(this);
        var categoryId = $btn.data('categoryId');
        $('#' + categoryId).toggle();
    });
});
```

Respective id of category div is added as data attribute on each button.

Complete sample code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btn-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
   var $btn = $(this);
   var categoryId = $btn.data('categoryId');
   $('#' + categoryId).toggle();
  });
 });
</script>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-category-id="Category1">Category 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-category-id="Category2">Category 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-category-id="Category3">Category 3</button>

  <div class="row">
   <!-- Category1 -->
   <div class="col-lg-4" id="Category1">Category 1</div>
   <!-- Category2 -->
   <div class="col-lg-4" id="Category2">Category 2</div>
   <!-- Category3 -->
   <div class="col-lg-4" id="Category3">Category 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That`s helpful. How to proceed to make "active" class added to visible category buttons and how to add additional all categories one.

Answer (score 0):

I could find Codepen sample using Isotope. Just the way I needed.

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-filter=".web">WEB</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-filter=".design">DESIGN</button>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid no-gutter">

    <div id="posts" class="row">
        <div id="1" class="item web col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="item web col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/nature">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="item design col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/people/1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="4" class="item design col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/technics">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="5" class="item web col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/transport/1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="6" class="item design col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/sports">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="7" class="item web col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600/business/1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="8" class="item design col-sm-3">
            <div class="item-wrap">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="//placekitten.com/600/600" title="Can you believe it??">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/bmodena/pen/Fybdu